# Никак не могу решить

Tags: javascript

В этом задании необходимо реализовать функцию, через которую можно управлять телефонной книгой.

Для управления телефонной книгой нужно реализовать три команды:

ADD — добавляет контакт
REMOVE_PHONE — удаляет номер
SHOW — возвращает содержимое телефонной книги

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание на coursera, ну никак не могу сделать, все просрочил. Скажите пожалуйста где у меня ошибки

Comment: Особенно удобно работать с кодом в виде картинки...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Наглядный ответ с пояснениями и рекомендациями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Шрифт великоват...

Comment: Хорошая идея...)))