# Объясните как делать

Tags: javascript

[image: Задание]

```
 // Телефонная книга
var phoneBook = {};

/**
 * @param {String} command
 * @returns {*} - результат зависит от команды
 */
module.exports = function (command) {



};
```

Вот в функции надо написать код, который при написании вышеупомянутых на картинке команд либо запишет, либо удалит или покажет имя и номер. Вот только не понятно само задание, как и от чего отталкиваться, скажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если Вас в тысячной толпе окликать: "эй, человек!" - Вы поймете, что именно в Вам обращаются? Так чего же Вы вопрос озаглавливаете **НИКАК**?

Comment: Уже второй: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765741/Никак-не-могу-решить

Answer (score 0):

Просто воспользуйся [split](https://javascript.ru/string/split), разделив команду на элемента, а потом анализируй эти элементы по отдельности.

Если нет времени читать про split: 
split("раз,два,три", ",") -> ["раз","два","три"]. 
split("12480282", "2") -> ["1","480","8"]. 
Сплит делит данную ему строку на части. Каждая часть отделена друг от друга символом, который указан во втором параметре.

Comment: я так и сделал, а вот как потом, подскажите?

Comment: @АлександрКарамушко, потом всё просто. Если первый элемент массива == "ADD", то во втором элементе массива будет номер(2 номера? Можно сделать сплит("второй элемент массива", ",")). Потом просто добавляем этот номер(номера?) в книгу.

Comment: Если первый элемент == "REMOVE_PHONE", то во втором элементе массива номер. Его тоже сплитаем и заносим в книгу. Если первый элемент == "SHOW", то просто выводим значения из книги.

Comment: Я вот сделал как вы сказали, всего ничего, элемент добавляется в книгу, но вот удаляться не хочет

Comment: @АлександрКарамушко, для начала нужно проверить, что всё записывается правильно. Если "SHOW" выводит всё нормально, то нужно искать заразу в хендлере(обработчике) "REMOVE_PHONE". Дополните свой вопрос и добавьте в него ваш код, возможно, мы найдём проблему.

Comment: сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @AlexanderK, извините меня, но куда вы пропали?

Answer (score 0):

На каждую операцию вы можете написать свою функцию, например для `ADD`

```
function AddNumber(name,phone)
```

и управляющую функцию

```
function phonebook(command)
```

в этой функции вам надо в зависимости от `сommand` вызывать разные функции. Саму command можно разбить на части методом string.split(' '). В зависимости от первого токена (первой части) вызываете разные команды.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: а функции для опр. операции писать в управляющей функции?

Comment: @АлександрКарамушко каждая функция пишется сама по себе, но они все буду вызываться из управляющей